# SwiftUI return View from a function constrained to a protocol

Tags: view, swiftui, protocols

Working on my first SwiftUI Project.

Trivial in UIKit since all Views are Classes.

Now, when I try to create a function that returns Views contrained to a type:

```swift
protocol RootView : View {
    func left() -> View     // 1
    func right() -> View    // 2
}

func viewFor(_ i : Int) -> RootView { //3
    
}
```

1,2 & 3 throw "Protocol View can only be used as a generic constrain....."

I have tried a bazillion combinations (using associated type in RootView, @ViewBuilder, etc)

just keeping it simple,

*How can we return a protocol-bound View from a function in SwiftUI?*

sorry if the solution is elemental, started SwiftUI precisely a week ago

Answer (score 1):

You need to use generics, like

```
protocol RootView : View {
    associatedtype LeftView: View
    associatedtype RightView: View
    
    func left() -> LeftView // 1
    func right() -> RightView // 2
}

func viewFor(_ i : Int) -> some RootView { // 3
  // ... your concrete root view constructed here
}
```

Comment: I tried that (and several variations)" last night, got to a segmentation fault 11 at the point where I insert that view inside another (which root is a Z View)